# Serialising missing values in trie

Tags: python, trie

There are two aspects to this question that are inter-related.

1. Change I've made to the `trie` module in python ([PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/trie), [GitHub](https://github.com/dhain/trie)) to make it serialisable (and deserialisable).

The change I made is [visible on GitHub](https://github.com/stephenpaulger/trie/commit/0246526ac75766a57f866d7ed44bef97850a762c). I added two functions to the `Node` class used in serialisation.

```
def __getstate__(self):
    return (self.parent, self.key, self.nodes, self.value)

def __setstate__(self, state):
    (self.parent, self.key, self.nodes, self.value) = state
    if type(self.value) == object:
        self.value = Node.no_value
```

The `Node` class uses an instance of `object` to signify that there is no value for that `Node`. If you serialise and deserialise a `Trie` of `Nodes` then the values are set to different instances of `object`, this is why I added a check for the type being `object` and replacing it with `Node.no_value`.

Is this a reasonable way of doing things? Is anyone likely to want to store an actual instance of `object`?

2. Is there a better way of signifying that a `Node` has no value, that is more robust to serialisation?

Answer (score 1):

Use None rather then Node.no_value.

None is the typical value to use for the absence of value. However, its possible that you actually want to store None in your trie, so that doesn't work.

Checking the type of the object is not really a good plan because somebody could decide to store plain objects in your trie. I would add another value, a boolean "self.value is Node.no_value", to the tuple in **setstate**. By checking that I could be sure that it works correctly.